# Grouped UITableView bottom border

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a small issue with a UITableView and it's background color. I am getting this strange footer at the end of the UITableView as you can see in the image below.

[image: Sample of the issue]

I've tried setting the border to [UIColor clearColor] but unfortunately that didn't help. Does anyone know why this is happening? (And how to fix it?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried changing the separator style, either in Interface Builder or programmatically by setting your UITableView's [`separatorStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/separatorStyle) property?

It looks like you may currently have this set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched`, which is [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle) as follows. You could try `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` instead.

> `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched`
>   The separator cell has double lines running across its width, giving it an etched look. This style is currently only supported for grouped-style table views.

Comment: You are right Clafou! I was reading on other questions that separatorStyle does not work on Grouped TableViews and didn't bother to try it anyway! Thanks!